# Xcode - UIButton inside for-loop

Tags: xcode, uibutton

I'm creating an application with a section that displays blog entries with information gathered from an XML-parser. I've added a transparent button over each entry like this:

```
UIButton *currentEntryButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    currentEntryButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, subViewWidth, currentEntryHeight);
```

I want the button to open up a webpage if there's a URL in the current entry. So what I want to do is make each button open the URL in a webView on click. But because I don't know how many entries there will be in the view I can't define a function to handle the on click event.

My plan was to define the actions when each button is created in the for-loop, but how can I do that?

I can't use

```
[currentEntryButton addTarget:self
               action:@selector(aMethod:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

because each button is supposed to commit an individual action.

This is what it looks like with roundRectButton style

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this in a table view?

Comment: No it's not. Each entry is in an individual subview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aMethod:` takes a parameter - the button. Hence you can tell which button was tapped, and you can perform a different action depending on which one it was. You can distinguish the buttons by title, by `tag` (if you give them different tags), and so on.

Comment: Hrm ok. So I can create one function that is called by all the buttons, and do something depending on the buttons tag? How do I define each buttons individual tag programmatically?

Comment: You are in a loop, you said. So keep setting the `tag` and keep adding 1 to that value.

Comment: The nice thing about this approach is that you can have an array of URLs and use the tags as the index into that array. But you should code the tags, e.g. 100, 101, 102 and then subtract 100 to get the index into the array.

Comment: Yes I think we're on to something =) Like this: UIButton *currentEntryButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [currentEntryButton addTarget:self
                               action:@selector(entryButtonPressed:currentTag)
                     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        currentEntryButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, subViewWidth, currentEntryHeight);

Comment: currentTag is an integer that is incremented with 1 each iteration. entryButtonPressed: - (void) entryButtonPressed:(NSInteger) tag {
    NSLog(@"Tag: %i", tag);
}

Comment: How do I pass on the integer to entryButtonPressed?

Comment: Please. Read what I said. Read the docs, even. I told you, the parameter to the action method when it is called will be *the button*. So you then ask for its tag.